# Select employees with no managers - two solutions

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements, filtering

I found the below test task on some testing platforms.
We have a table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(20),
    "managerId" integer,
    CONSTRAINT employees_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

An employee is a manager if any other employee has their `managerId` set to this eomployee's id. Carol is a manager if at least on other employee has their `managerId` set to Carol's `id`.

Write a query that select **only** the names of employees who are not managers.

I came up with 2 possible solutions for this:

Solution 1:

```sql
select e.name
from public.employees as e
where not exists (select e1."managerId" from public.employees as e1 where e1."managerId" = e.id);
```

Solution 2:

```sql
select e.name
from employees as e 
left outer join public.employees as e1 on e.id = e1."managerId"
group by e.name
having count(e1.id) = 0;
```

There are some automated tests running to verify the code is correct.

My first solution passes the validation but my second solution fails. The message only says: "Workers have managers: Wrong answer". Certainly, I do not know the content of that test. I tried to come up with different test scenarios, where the above two solution brings up different results, but was unable to come up with one.

Do you have any suggestions for test data that brings up different results for my two solutions? I would really like to know where my second solution fails.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the second to be incorrect (although unlikely in practice).

- If two people have the same name, and one is a manager and one isn't, then the GROUP BY will combine these and treat them as a manager because it is grouping by 'name' only

For example, if your data is as follows, the second solution will not find any non-managers.

```
id          name                 managerId
----------- -------------------- -----------
1           Spartacus            NULL
2           Spartacus            1
```

Options

- People often use the approach you've got in the second answer, but instead of grouping, use IS NULL from the second table (this means you don't need to process a 'GROUP BY', you just find blanks).
  e.g.,

```
select e.name
from employees as e 
left outer join public.employees as e1 on e.id = e1."managerId"
where e1.id IS NULL
```

- An alternative is to ensure the grouping includes the primary key - ensuring that each row in the original table is treated uniquely e.g.,

```
select e.id, e.name
from employees as e 
left outer join public.employees as e1 on e.id = e1."managerId"
group by e.id, e.name
having count(e1.id) = 0;
```

For the automated test results to pass you, you'd then need to ensure you only selected the name (not ID). Depending on the SQL product used, you may be able to just select the name; alternatively, you'd need to turn the above into a CTE or sub-query, and then select the name from that.

Note: In your second solution, you missed one of the `public.` for one of the tables.